# phaser: f1(a, b, f2) - what if f2 has parameters?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

(in Phaser, based in javascript,)

In a situation like this:

```
f1(a, b, f2);
```

I want to pass parameters to f2.

```
function f2 (x,y){
    //code
}
```

but if I try,

```
f1(a, b, f2(x,y));
```

...it gives me an error.

(P.S I know sometimes it automatically carries a and b over as parameter but what if i don't want to use a and b?)

here is my actual code

```
game.time.events.add(TELEPORT_CASTTIME, teleport);
```

teleport is my function, but i want to pass parameters to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function f2(x, y) {    
    return function() {
        //code, you can use x and y
    }
}
```

Then:

```
f1(a, b, f2(x,y));
```